# É possível chamar por OnClick de TextView uma nova Activity?

Tags: java, android

Olá, estou tentando chamar um activity novo por meio de `OnClick` num `TextView`, mas ao executar a aplicação gera um crash.

Eis a activity de a partir que estou tentando passar:

```
public class sdActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "TesteGigaservicesAPP";

//list view dos produtos
public ListView lv;

//list view adapter
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

//barra de busca
AutoCompleteTextView inputSearch;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sd);

    //produtos da busca
   String[] produtos = {
           "Produto 1",
           "Produto 2",
           "Produto 3",
           "Produto 4",
           "Produto 5"
   };

   lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listaDProdutos);
   inputSearch = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.barradepesquisa);

   //popula a lista
   adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, produtos);
   lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    //

   //aciona a barra de buscas

    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        sdActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }



        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });



    /*problemas de implementação*/

    TextView ver = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.product_name);

    ver.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(sdActivity.this, ProdutoActivity.class));
            //teste para passar sob o elemento de uma view de layout
        }
    });






    //botão que volta a página anterior
    Button btVoltarUm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btVoltarUm);

    btVoltarUm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(sdActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    });
}
}
```

O item `product_name` fica em um arquivo de layout separado que está como list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Single ListItem -->

    <!-- Nome do produto listado -->


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Esse é meu arquivo de manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.testegigaservices.testegigaservices">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".sdActivity"
        android:label="@string/pgBusca"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".produtoActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: "ao executar a aplicação gera um crash" - O primeiro passo neste caso é consultar o *Log* para ver qual a mensagem de erro e qual a linha em que deu erro. Deve pegar nessa mensagem de erro e colocar na pergunta

Comment: ok, das consultas no logcat inserirei os logs na próxima tentativa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você precisa observar é o seguinte:

1º O `findViewById()` dentro da activity está diretamente ligado ao seu respectivo layout, nesse caso:

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_sd);`

2º O erro provavelmente acontece justamente porque o `findViewById()` está procurando pelo **TextView** que na verdade está em um outro layout (`list_item.xml`), consequentemente ele não vai achar:

3º Sempre poste a mensagem de **erro**, para que fique mais fácil lhe ajudar.

4º Solução para reconhecer o click em um dos items da lista:

```
private OnItemClickListener quandoOhItemForClicado = new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
           startActivity(new Intent(sdActivity.this, ProdutoActivity.class));
    }
};

listView.setOnItemClickListener(quandoOhItemForClicado);
```

Comment: ok, entendi a lógica.

Answer (score 4):

**Em primeiro lugar caso essa não seja a solução, cole o LOG para que possamos analisar.**

Verifique se o nome de sua activity no AndroidManifest está coerente com sua classe, percebi que você está declarando uma activity no manifesto e quando tentar startar a nova activity passa uma referência  com letra maiúscula.

```
<activity android:name=".ProdutoActivity"></activity>
```